# Phalcon - add css assets collection

Tags: php, phalcon

I have a problem to add css assets to the collection called from view layout.phtml

This is my code:

```
<?php echo $this->tag->getDoctype() ?>
<html>
    <head>  
        <?php $this->assets->outputCss('header') ?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php $this->assets->get('header')->addCss('test.css'); ?>
        <?php $this->assets->get('footer')->addJs('test.js'); ?>

        <?php $this->assets->outputJs('footer') ?>    
    </body>
 </html>
```

And this is output in browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
  <head>            
  </head>         
  <body>                                                  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test.js"></script>          
  </body>
</html>
```

Why is not the output of CSS tag in the head?

Comment: You have to add CSS in controller not in view. Second mistake is trying to add CSS' in body. Place of CSS' is head. [Docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/assets.html).

Answer (score 1):

The Assets component basically works like this:

- You add your assets to the service in your controller action (because that's where the application logic is supposed to reside)
- In your view, you can then access the Assets component and request the output of single assets or an entire asset group

Suppose the view you mentioned is displayed via this controller:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Add your header assets here
        $this->assets
            ->collection('header')
            ->addCss('test.css');

        // Add your footer assets here
        $this->assets
            ->collection('footer')
            ->addJs('test.js');
    }
}
```

Now your view should look like this:

```
<?php echo $this->tag->getDoctype() ?>
<html>
    <head>  
        <?php $this->assets->outputCss('header') ?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php $this->assets->outputJs('footer') ?>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing missing from this answer.  Where to put test.css?  What is the path for addCss() relative to?